# Upgrade To 11.10 - Issue With Quad Monitors

Tags: 11.10, xorg, multiple-monitors

I am having issues setting up my machine to use quad monitors. This was all working fine in 11.04 but since upgrading I have had no luck getting the configuration to work. If I use the same xorg.conf as I had working in 11.04 I get 4 clones of the same image on the monitors. Not only this but if I click on an icon such as firefox in the launch bar, X restarts. Getting two monitors working is simple and if I just remove the xorg.conf Ubuntu is able to detect the two monitors and set them up correctly.

I am not bothered about any fancy effects but it would be nice if I could get the system up and running with four monitors as I had before. I am not using the ati drivers, just the open source radeon driver as one of my cards isn't supported by the newer ATI drivers. I am using two different ATI cards on the system :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Mobility Radeon HD 3600 Series
```

The xorg.conf is shown below:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "monitor2"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "monitor3"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "monitor4"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver "radeon"
    BusID "PCI:2:0:0"
    Option "DRI" "off"
    Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1_2"
    Driver "radeon"
    BusID "PCI:2:0:0"
    Option "DRI" "off"
    Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Option "ZaphodHeads"   "DVI-0"
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver "radeon"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "DRI" "off"
    Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Option "ZaphodHeads"   "VGA-0"
    Identifier  "Card2_2"
    Driver "radeon"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "DRI" "off"
    Screen 1
    Option "Rotate" "left"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "left"
    Device "Card1"
    Monitor "monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "middle"
    Device "Card1_2"
    Monitor "monitor2"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "right"
    Device "Card2"
    Monitor "monitor3"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "farright"
    Device "Card2_2"
Monitor "monitor4"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option  "Xinerama"  "True"
    Option  "AIGLX" "False"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout1"
    Screen 0 "left" 0 0
    Screen "middle" RightOf "left"
    Screen "right" RightOf "middle"
    Screen "farright" RightOf "right"
    Option        "Xinerama" "On"
EndSection
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried ATI drivers?

Comment: I've tried the ATI drivers but not a good option because one of my graphics cards isn't supported by them so I end up with a dual monitor config.

Comment: do you have `amdcccle` installed?

Comment: No. As far as I know that only works with the ATI drivers.